# Can an IP Address be used as the FQDN when requesting a SSL Certificate?

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

When filling out a request for a SSL Certificate, can the IP address be used for the "Common Name"?

**update:**
We have a new production box that doesn't have a public domain name. Just a public IP. But we need to request a SSL certificate. I'm working on the domain name, but in the meantime, if I can push through a cert request with just the public IP, then I can keep something moving.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you want to do that?

Comment: @JimG. Updated to explain. As far as I know, that box doesn't have a public domain name to enter in the request. Just a public IP.

Comment: You should wait for the certificate issued for your domain and signed by a CA. Meantime, you can use a self signed certificate, but this is not recommended from the security point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to: [RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) , yes, it is possible.
However the SSL client might not be fully compliant and you have to test all your supported SSL clients to see how they are performing the certificate validation.

> "The client determines the type (e.g., DNS name or IP address) of the
> reference identity and performs a comparison between the reference
> identity and each subjectAltName value of the corresponding type
> until a match is produced.  Once a match is produced, the server's
> identity has been verified, and the server identity check is
> complete.  Different subjectAltName types are matched in different
> ways.  Sections 3.1.3.1 - 3.1.3.3 explain how to compare values of
> various subjectAltName types. "

.

> "3.1.3.2.  Comparison of IP Addresses
>
> When the reference identity is an IP address, the identity MUST be
> converted to the "network byte order" octet string representation
> [IP] [IPv6].  For IP Version 4, as specified in RFC 791, the octet
> string will contain exactly four octets.  For IP Version 6, as
> specified in RFC 2460, the octet string will contain exactly sixteen
> octets.  This octet string is then compared against subjectAltName
> values of type iPAddress.  A match occurs if the reference identity
> octet string and value octet strings are identical."

.

> "   o  Identifiers other than fully qualified DNS domain names.
>
> ```
>   Some certification authorities issue server certificates based on
>   IP addresses, but preliminary evidence indicates that such
>   certificates are a very small percentage (less than 1%) of issued
>   certificates.  Furthermore, IP addresses are not necessarily
>   reliable identifiers for application services because of the
>   existence of private internets [PRIVATE], host mobility, multiple
>   interfaces on a given host, Network Address Translators (NATs)
>   resulting in different addresses for a host from different
>   locations on the network, the practice of grouping many hosts
>   together behind a single IP address, etc.  Most fundamentally,
>   most users find DNS domain names much easier to work with than IP
>   addresses, which is why the domain name system was designed in the
>   first place.  We prefer to define best practices for the much more
>   common use case and not to complicate the rules in this
>   specification. "
> ```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the CA. I know that the Comodo InstantSSL will allow a ip address. It is a business validated SSL Certificate.

Answer (score -1):

You can get SSL for public IP from [Zero SSL](https://zerossl.com/). They even provide the trial period for 30 days. You can create 3 certificates for free.
Also they have self explanatory documentation for easy integration.
Once you are able to generate and use SSL, you can buy it later.

As you need to use it for IIS, you will need .pfx format certificate, that you can create by using [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/source/) from the certificates you get from zero ssl. Check this [link](https://help.zerossl.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058296034-Certificate-Format) from generating .pfx for IIS.

Note: I am not affiliated with ZeroSSL in any way. I have used SSL certificate from ZeroSSL for the exact situation mentioned in the question.

Comment: Why does this feel like spam?

Comment: Its not a spam. I am not anywhere associated to zeroSSL. I have used it at my workplace for creating SSL for web-apps I create. Also there are not much CAs that provide SSL on Public IP. So it will be use full for someone who is looking for the SSL for public IP. Check out my own [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1131330/ssl-certificate-for-subdomain-which-is-routed-to-public-ip-masked-on-firewall) on SSL for clarification of you doubt. @vidarlo Requesting you to remove downvote.

Comment: Hi, please edit to state you are not affiliated with zerossl, as is, your answer is really wrote like other spam we got on the site. If the product if free, then your answer can be ok, but if paid it's borderline to be removed. Thanks !

Comment: As the answer from 10 years ago indicates, it is technically possible. But almost no-one engages in this unorthodox practice, in particular the larger authorities.

Comment: @yagmoth555 it is giving trial period to try it out. that can at least give some time to get clarification on how SSL certificates resolves / works. Just as in my case, we had to get SSL for public IP only. There are other free providers also like let's Encrypt, that is widely used. But only a few provides SSL on public IP.

Comment: @GregAskew very true, it exposes your IP, so as I learned in last few months is getting SSL on public IP is not a good idea. But in some cases if it is required, we can get it. I just shared what I knew, which may help someone. As question may be old, but someone like me need the same even today.